# "ECHO" showing up in the middle of generating random characters for some reason?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

So my code here:

```
@echo off
pause
setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set alfanum=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
:a
timeout /t 1
set generator=
FOR /L %%b IN (0, 1, 5) DO (
SET /A rnd_num=!RANDOM! * 62 / 32768 + 1
for /F %%c in ('echo %%alfanum:~!rnd_num!^,1%%') do set generator=!generator!%%c
)

echo %generator%
goto generator
```

Is slightly broken because sometimes "ECHO" shows up in the middle of generating. for example:

```
vMECHO8ECHOE <<
DQTGv0
aECx5i
lLECHOO3H <<
cOd4ECHOg <<
6950pC
```

Help? running on Windows 10 CMD.

Comment: Remove the `+ 1` from your `set /A` command line and you will be fine (you point past the string in `!alfanum!`). Anyway, The `for /F` loop is not necessary, just replace it by the line `for %%a in (!rnd_num!) do set "generator=!generator!!alfanum:~%%a,1!"`, or `call set "generator=!generator!%%alfanum:~!rnd_num!,1%%"` (slower)…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `+ 1` from your `set /A` command line and you will be fine:

```cmd
set /A "rnd_num=!RANDOM!*62/32768"
```

Which can be simplified to:

```cmd
set /A "rnd_num=!RANDOM!%%62"
```

You actually point past the string in `!alfanum!`, because the position index for sub-string expansion is zero-based, meaning `0` points to the first character, and `61` to the last one in your 62-character string. Your current code returns `62` as the greatest possible random number, so the sub-string expansion returns an empty string, which lets the `echo` command in your `for /F` loop output `ECHO is {on|off}.`, resulting in the result `ECHO` due to the default token string `tokens=1` of `for /F`.

Anyway, The `for /F` loop is not necessary, just replace it by the line:

```cmd
rem /* The standard `for` loop ensures that the value of `!rnd_num!` is expanded
rem    BEFORE delayed sub-string expansion of `!alfanum:~...!` occurs: */
for %%a in (!rnd_num!) do set "generator=!generator!!alfanum:~%%a,1!"
```

Or (slower):

```cmd
rem /* The `call` command ensures that the sub-string of `%alfanum:~...%`
rem    is expanded AFTER delayed expansion of `!rnd_num!` occurs: */
call set "generator=!generator!%%alfanum:~!rnd_num!,1%%"
```

Answer (score 1):

Substring modification is 0 indexed. ensure the index you use is EQU to the number of characters - 1

```bat
FOR /L %%n IN (0,1,5)Do For /F "delims=" %%c In ( 'SET /A "_r=!RANDOM! %% 62"' )Do (
 Set "generator=!generator!!alfanum:~%%c,1!"
)
```

Comment: You don't even need the assignment to `_r`, just keep the expression `!RANDOM! %% 62`, the result is then anyway output to the console. Worth mentioning that this works since `set /A` is executed in Command Prompt context by `for /F`, in contrast to batch context where `set /A` doesn't return anything. Because of invocation of new Command Prompt instances per `for /L` loop iteration this method is slower than avoiding `for /F`. But still I do like this approach!